# how set condition for text field. text?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uitextfield, uipickerview

```
if([txtField1.text  intValue] == nil  && [txtField2.text  intValue] == nil && [txtField3.text  intValue] == nil  && [txtField4.text  intValue] == nil  && [txtField5.text  intValue] == nil && [txtField6.text  intValue] == nil && [txtField7.text  intValue] == nil && [txtField8.text  intValue] == nil )
{
    UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message: @"Please complete your test." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [info show];
     [info release];

}
else if(txtField1.text == NULL  || txtField2.text   == NULL || txtField3.text  == NULL || txtField4.text   == NULL  || txtField5.text  == NULL || txtField6.text == NULL ||txtField7.text == NULL || txtField8.text  == NULL )
{
    UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message: @"Please complete your test." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [info show];
    [info release];

}
else{
fourthScreen=[[FourthScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.fourthScreen animated:YES];
}
```

in above code i have 8 text field. for that i have define a condition that is when all text field is blank of nil the show alert view msg. and it is working. But when i define as like when any one has nil or blank text field the also show alert view but it not show. The problem is that when i enter integer value"0" then it also show alert view but i want that it not show for '0' value. The value chosen by picke4r view. how set the code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if([txtName.text length] == 0 || [txtName.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
         // Alert here
}
```

Test length to 0 or compare string to a blank string.

Comment: The second comparison is redundant. An `NSString` can only be equal to `""` if it has length 0.

Answer (score 1):

No need for first condition any way if any text field is empty alert should prompt up.
Try this

```
if([txtField1.text length] == 0  || [txtField2.text length] == 0 || [txtField3.text length]  == 0 || [txtField4.text length   == 0]  || [txtField5.text length]  == 0 || [txtField6.text length == 0 ||[txtField7.text length] == 0 || [txtField8.text length]  == 0 )
{
    UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message: @"Please complete your test." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [info show];
    [info release];

}
else{
fourthScreen=[[FourthScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.fourthScreen animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can compare 0 like this.**

```
 if ([txtName.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
     // 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the length of the String in your textFields is 0:

```
if ([txtField1.text  length] == 0) {
    //your stuff here
}
```

This will hold true exactly if there is nothing entered at all in the text field. You will not need the "distinction" between `nil` and `NULL` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if ([txtName.text isEqualToString:@""])

{

}